# After event not fired using fade flexslider iPad

Tags: flexslider

I am using the flexslider after event to trigger another function but the after event in flexslider does not work in combination with fade on an iPad.
Using slide as animation solves the problem but I need fade instead of slide.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
      slideshow: true,
    animation: "fade",
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
    start: function(){animation()},
    after: function(){animation()},
    before: function(){}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I needed to execute a function in the after callback and it didn't fire off on ipad.

I made a quick workaround and I've used the before method instead, it didn't have any downsides for me because I just needed to update an external slide counter.

I have looked into the flexslider 2.1 [code](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/zipball/master) and I think that the lines 520-521 or 527-530 are causing problems here:

520-521

```
slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).fadeOut(vars.animationSpeed, vars.easing);
slider.slides.eq(target).fadeIn(vars.animationSpeed, vars.easing, slider.wrapup);
```

527-530

```
slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).bind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend", function() {
      // API: after() animation Callback
      vars.after(slider);
});
```

You can debug it if you want, I hope you'll find it useful.